# php connect to server

Tags: php, sql-server, connection

I am trying to connect to a Network drive remotely using authentication using PHP the network drive is data(\drive_name)(T:).

What I am trying to do is access a network drive externally/remotely to view/download documents.I will have about 4 users that will need to access this from own lap tops etc.

If possible can you give me some pointers on how to achieve this.

It Maybe that I can not use PHP and need to look at an alternative

If you require any additional information please let me know

Thanks in advance

David

Comment: Just mount it as a network drive and use the usual filesystem functions (fopen, readfile, etc)

Comment: Hi Gordon Thanks for your reply - do you have any examples on how this can be done? What are the implications of mounting as a network drive.The drive is visible on my local network. by making these changes will that still be available? Thanks David

Comment: Hi All I have tried the following and I am confused on how I should connect. <code><?php 
 $data=file("http://djennings.co.uk/wat-sql-02SP"); 
$data=join("\n",$data); 

$fout=fopen($outputfile,"w"); 
fwrite($fout,$data); 
fclose($fout); 

?></code> The network server is called wat-sql-02SP and the domain is djennings.co.uk.  Thanks in advance David